# Les say avg time to travel in train from NY to NJ is 75 mins

Tags: percentages

Les say avg time to travel in train from NY to NJ is 75 mins.

Les say they get a faster train and they are 1000 times faster. What would be the new avg time to travel from NY to NJ?

I got 75 / 10.00 which is 0.75 sec?

Answer (score 1):

1) $75\cdot60 = 4500$ seconds

2) $4500 / 1000 = 4.5$ seconds

So answer is $4.5$ seconds. You can't just divide $75$ by a thousand because there are $60$ seconds in a minute, not $100$